# KendoChart filtering based on the checked event is not working properly

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am doing one project using kendo controls,I have kendo chart and tree-view with check-boxes in my application.My requirement is to filter the kendo chart based on the checked event in tree-view.And here only 2 check-boxes are selecting at a time.On page load only 2 items will be displaying in the chart.

My fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/73/

My treeview on change event code is

```
$("#treeview").on("change", function (e) {
    var chart = $("#myChart").data("kendoChart");

    var checkedSeries = [];

    $("#treeview").find(":checked").each(function() {
        var nodeText = $(this).parent().parent().text();

        $.each(series, function(index, series) {
            if (series.field == nodeText) {
                checkedSeries.push(series);
            }
        });
    });

    chart.options.series = checkedSeries;
    chart.refresh();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove extra spaces from you text node... Try adding `trim` when you compute `nodeText` on the `change` handler function:

```
var nodeText = $(this).parent().parent().text().trim();
```

Comment: Thank you its working but in page-load all the data is displaying,i want to display only 2 values(which are are in checked) in chart in pageload..?

Comment: Please, review the fiddle that you post in your original question. It also displays all the series, doesn't have to do with `.trim()`.